# vlookup function pulling data from another worksheet where lookup_value is a range of values

Tags: excel

I'm trying to pull information from a data table(valuedata) from another worksheet.

Formula look like this =vlookup(c1,valuedata,5,false)

c1 is the column of value data (e.g 2.41)

valuedata first column consist of lookup values where it goes like this,
<2.00,  2-2.09,  2.1-2.19,  2.2-2.29,  2.3-2.39,  2.4-2.49,  >2.5

How do I use vlookup function for c1 data(2.41) to be able to have it recognize that it falls under the 2.4-2.49 category where it will be able to pull data from that row?

Comment: Use `INDEX-MATCH`. `INDEX` can get you values that are equal, less than or greater than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` works by checking the given value against the keys... the last parameter of the function tells it whether to use an exact match or not... Your value of `false` means exact - so that should be `true` for starters.

Then comes the lookup list... in the non-exact mode, it will return the first item that is not larger than your value and will assume ascending order of the lookup values. If you have the ranges as your lookup list, it is a text comparison and may behave somewhat oddly. However, if you add a column containing the numeric lower limit of the range (i.e. 0, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5) you can then do `=vlookup(c1,valuedata_including_new_lower_limit,6,true)`

Comment: Guess I'll have to rebuild my data table format, thanks for the answer.